# How to set specific query parameters for docs in a sub collection in firestroe 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to set a specific quarry for a sub collection when using a snapshot ?
I am tring to sort sub collection resutls by createdAt  with the limit of last 5

```js
 useEffect(() => {
      //const querydata = query(docRefComm, orderBy('createdAt'), limit(5));
      let collectionRef = collection(db, 'Comm', docId, 'messages');
      const unsub = onSnapshot(collectionRef , (doc) => {
       doc.forEach((el) => {
          console.log(el.data());
        });
      });
      return () => {
        unsub();
      };
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Where did you fail? `query(ref, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), limit(5))` should work for the last 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a `query()` using `CollectionReference` as shown below:

```
let collectionRef = collection(db, 'Comm', docId, 'messages');
const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('createdAt'), limit(5))
      
const unsub = onSnapshot(q , (qSnap) => { 

})
```

Checkout [Listen to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) in the documentation.